# Why some built-in functions do not have keyword arguments

Tags: python

I like the named parameters and find it much clearer when I can use it, so why is it not allowed for some built-in functions?

From the doc, `next`'s signature is `next(iterator[, default])`

But in shell:

```
>>> next((x for x in range(2)), default=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: next() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why). 

People might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it: `range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`